# Restkit how to do mapping (to many) relationships by primary key

Tags: ios, mapping, key, restkit

I've seen from [a changes for Restkit that was commited about 6 months ago](https://github.com/mcfedr/RestKit/commit/f0d22e4c3e5413de4b6df4eaf7d88960078e3147) -- that Restkit supports mapping JSON structures with arrays of foreign keys：

```
supports structure such as:
{
  items: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
  itemgroups: [{items: [1, 2]}, {items:[2, 3]}]
}
```

My question is, can anyone show me how I can use this feature with core data?

I did check the Restkit source code and found [the following code demonstrated the usage of changes](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Tests/Logic/CoreData/RKManagedObjectMappingOperationTest.m). But they don't seems to work with CoreData.

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *humanMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKHuman class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];

humanMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"railsID";
[humanMapping mapAttributes:@"name", @"favoriteCatID", @"catIDs", nil];
[humanMapping mapRelationship:@"cats" withMapping:catMapping];
[humanMapping connectRelationship:@"cats" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"catIDs"];
```

The catIDs property in the human object is an NSArray:

```
@interface RKHuman : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *railsID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *cats;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *catIDs;
```

The test case is achieve via NSArray. But we all know that Coredata can't generate an **NSArray type** property. So this demo code doesn't make sense in the real world, this is just pure for testing purpose. Does anyone know how I should use this feature: to-many relationship via primary key?